# How to create 404 error page in Dash (plotly)?

Tags: http-status-code-404, plotly-dash

In Flask I can generate 404 (https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/errorhandling/):

```
@app.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    output = render_template("404.html",
                             title = 'Page not found')
```

but how create 404 page in Dash? With 404 response status.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Flask app and pass it to your Dash app. Then you could use the Flask app for the error handling and for redirecting to your Dash app:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect
from dash import Dash
import dash_html_components as html

server = Flask(__name__)
app = Dash(__name__, server=server, url_base_pathname='/dash/')
app.layout = html.P("Hello World")


@server.errorhandler(404)
def page_not_found(error):
    return render_template("404.html", title="Page not found")


@server.route("/dash")
def dashboard():
    return redirect("/dash/")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    server.run()
```